# For the metric $d(x, y) = |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}|$ describe the open ball $B_r$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

For the metric $d(x, y) = |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}|$ at  $(0, \infty)$, describe the open ball $B_r$

My try:

Let $C = \{\frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x} + r\}\quad$ y $\quad D = \{\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{y} + r\}$

The open ball is:

$\quad B_r(x) = \{y \quad| \quad |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| < r \} = C - D$

I don´t know if it´s correct to discribe $B_r$ like this.

Comment: What set is this supposed to be a metric for? Is it meant to be a metric for the set of all positive numbers?

Comment: Is for all positive numbers. Then $B_r$ is just defined at the first quadrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in your question, we have the following inequality:
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right| < r$$
We can rewrite this as:
$$\frac{1}{x}-r < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x}+r$$
$$\implies \frac{1-rx}{x} < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1+rx}{x}$$
Now, there are two cases:

**Case 1: $1-rx \leq 0$**

In this case, the first inequality is obvious, since a non-positive number is always less than a positive number, so we are left with:
$$\frac{1}{y} < \frac{1+rx}{x}$$
Take the reciprocal to find that:
$$\frac{x}{1+rx} < y$$
Thus, we see that we can describe $B_r(x)$ as:
$$B_r(x)=\left(\frac{x}{1+rx}, +\infty\right)$$

Now, I will leave it to you to finish the second case, which is when $1-rx > 0$. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on a calculator should give you some ideia, for example look at [this graph on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xtvazxagez).